# Howto create a context binding from a queried object with odata v4 model

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have access to a database via OData V4 which holds body weight measurements which are represented by two attributes 1. Weight and 2. DateTimeOffsetOfMeasurement. I want to filter for the most recent Measurement value, i.e. most recent DateTimeOffsetOfMeasurement, and I would like to bind this value to an sap.m.Input field for display in the UI.

I am trying to use the sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel for my work, I do not want to switch to ajax or something different.

The OData V4 Query to get the relevant object would look as follows:

http://localhost:8080/odata4/svc//BodyWeight?$orderby=WeightMeasurementDateTime%20desc&$top=1

Now my problem is, that I do not know how I can create a context binding to connect the data source with the datamodel and the model with the input field. It would be great if someone could provide a Javascript solution and the respective solution for an SAPUI5 xml view.

For a list binding in a xml view I found the following solution working.

"{  path: '/BodyWeight',
  length: 1,
  sorter: {
        path: 'WeightMeasurementDateTime',
  descending: true}

However, the length value here is not part of the official documentation and I am not sure if this breaks something. Moreover, I need to get a context binding and not a list binding to reach my goal with the Input field. My idea was to create a list binding in the first step, maybe with sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel.bindList, and then extract the context from the first element afterwards. However, I have not found a way to do tis.

Every comment is welcome. Thanks a lot for your help!

Best regards,
 Christoph